# Adding object/class to a list with a different type

Tags: java, list, class, object, arraylist

Basicly, I want to how if it's possible in Java to do following:

```
public static ArrayList<Script> scripts = new ArrayList<Script>();
scripts.add(new TestScript()); //TestScript extends Script class.
```

I've tried some different things with type casting, and asking some of my friends. No one seem to have an answer. But I know it would be possible.. maybe? If so, how do I make the above work? If it doesn't, what else can I do to get the same effect?

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? Why ask **us** if it works?

Answer (score 2):

`TestScript` should be a subclass of `Script`. A collection of an object can hold the objects of the same class and all of its subclasses.

No casting is required because TestScript is logically a Script as it extends from Script.

Comment: It is already mentioned in the question, that TestScript extends Script. See line #2 of his code snippet.

Comment: The question may be calling `TestScript` methods on the elements.

Comment: Exactly. My TestScript extends Script, which in theory should work, but doesn't. Can it be something to do, that my script above, which is a "ScriptManager" is in a subfolder, but the TestScript is in the root?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration should be  `ArrayList<? super Script>`

Comment: I wouldn't say *should*.

Comment: Masud: No, it won't work. Try it. Adding `TestScript` instances won't work, since it could be an `ArrayList<FooScript>` where `FooScript` extends `Script` but *not* `TestScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. You'll do as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Script> scripts = new ArrayList<Script>();
scripts.add(new TestScript()); //TestScript extends Script class.
```

and to traverse,

```
for( Script scr : scripts){
    scr.someMethodOfScript(); //no testscript methods available
    if(scr instanceof TestScript){
        TestScript tscr = (TestScript) scr;
        //call TestScript methods on tscr
    }
}
```

You'll need an instanceof and a  cast for any TestScript methods not available in Script.